# Songs not in "Music" but seen in smart playlist created for that artist

Tags: itunes, playlist, smart-playlist

I added a CD to my iTunes Library yesterday.  I could not find them under Recently Added playlist or under Music.  So, I created a Smart Playlist for the Artist and they do show up.

When I choose Artists and Albums, the music is not there. The songs only show up in the Smart Playlist for the Artist.

I have looked in the iTunes folder and the Artist's folder is definitely there and has the album's folder and all of the songs.

I can also play the songs when I click on them in the Smart Playlist (so one of the correct file types to play in iTunes).

I have also closed and restarted iTunes several times and it still does not work.

I opened music on my iPhone last night and noticed that the artist/album/songs do appear in the cloud.

How can I get them to show up in iTunes in the Music/Albums, Artist, Songs lists on my Mac?

Linda

Comment: Right click on the songs and go to Get Info and select the options tab.  Make sure the media type is Music.

Comment: Yes it is. Good try though.

Comment: Under Get Info, what extension is listed for the files? What are the settings on your Recently Added playlist?

Comment: It solved itself after rebooting my computer.  I have a little less than 16,000 songs. Or maybe my computer is getting overwhelmed since it is almost full and has slowed down. (New Mac has already been bought and shipped :-)